# How to input random username in iMacros?

Tags: imacros

How can I input random username using iMacros? I wanna create a simple sign up bot that will use random username every time. Any suggestion please.

Comment: Take a look at the previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31734028/fill-up-fields-with-random-names-with-imacro . The idea can be similar.

Comment: Or you can make a script that goes on a site. Site generates random username, you grab it and use it... I would use JS for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use 2 methods for this:

**1)** Purely random strings for one time use only.
Use this line to generate a string where in this case i<6 means the length of the output string and * 25 means the length of the array of letters to choose from

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var letters = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','w','x','y','z']; var string = ''; for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){string += letters[parseInt(Math.random() * 25)]}; string")
```

to use the string add {{!VAR1}} where you need the username like so:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:createaccount ATTR=ID:FirstName CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
```

**2)** Use pre-generated strings from a text file (Can be generated manually or by a 'random name generator' online), this allows you to save credentials for future use.
Generate a file.csv where each line holds comma seperated info for one user. Info is accessed as {{!COL1}} for first item, 2 for second item etc'

```
SET !DATASOURCE C:\Temp\stackoverflow.csv
'where to start in the csv file
SET !LOOP 1337 
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#new_post>DIV>P>DIV>DIV" CHARS={{!COL1}}
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="#new_post>DIV>P>DIV>DIV" CHARS={{!COL2}}
```

stackoverflow.csv file example:

```
pika,chuu,easypassword123
wobbu,ffet,mypassword
chari,zard,123456
```

I hope this helped, this is also my first comment ever.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new in iMacros. Could you please tell me how to make GUI or exe file? I would be very thankful to you if you give steps by steps tuts for beginner. :)

Comment: If you mean how to run this macro as easy as a double click on an exe file, the solution that I work with is running this command in a CMD window:
<code> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"  imacros://run/?m=stackoverflow.iim <code>
this code opens firefox and starts the macro automatically. To close the browser after it runs you will need to add to the macro TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS and TAB CLOSE
you can add the cmd command above to a batch file and run it like an exe

Comment: I have iMacros Enterprise edition and I run a CPA forum. So I'm willing to create some bot to support users and publish it. So I need a EXE file for publishing. If I give them .imm file, they could easily crack it. This why I need your help. :)